# Insert A String That Contains An Incremental Value

Tags: sql-server-2014

I need to setup 1000 test users in our DB. The users are named like this:

- TestUser0001
- TestUser0002
- TestUser0003

And so on up to 1000. The thing is, I don't want to write 1000 insert statements to get this done. My approach was to use an IF/ELSE and use several variables so that I can check when the incremental value is within a range where I can put the appropriate zeros in place.

There has to be an easier way to do this, but I can't think of of it. The leading zeros are the biggest problem.

Anyone know of an easy way to accomplish this task? How would you do this?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this is to use FORMAT(). You could pass your variable that holds the incremented value into the FORMAT function and the format would be '0000'. Like so:

FORMAT(@IncVar, '0000')